# adding different class/style to rows that variable fulfills the condition

Tags: mysql, styles, row, echo

The problem is that all images are displayed with opacity: 0.4. I need different style to each row that value from number column is less than 100.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {       
            $progres = $row['number'];
            $num_rows++;    
            echo "$progres <br/>";
            echo "<div class='right_achiev'>";
            echo '<div id="box1" class="box">'; 
            echo '<span class="caption simple-caption">';
            echo '<p class="sq1">'.$row['name'].'</p>';
            echo '<p class="unlok">UNLOCKED:<br/> 2014-01-09 16:25 </p>';
            echo '</span>';

            if ($progres < 100)
            {
                echo "<img class='achiev_icon' src='".$row['icon']."'/>";   
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "<img class='achiev_icon' style='opacity:0.4' src='".$row['icon']."'/>";   
            }

            echo "</div>";  
            echo "</div>";  
        }
```

Comment: what type is the number filed in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use this code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {       
        $progres = intval($row['number']);
        $num_rows++;    
        echo "$progres <br/>";
        echo "<div class='right_achiev'>";
        echo '<div id="box1" class="box">'; 
        echo '<span class="caption simple-caption">';
        echo '<p class="sq1">'.$row['name'].'</p>';
        echo '<p class="unlok">UNLOCKED:<br/> 2014-01-09 16:25 </p>';
        echo '</span>';

        if ($progres < 100)
        {
            echo "<img class='achiev_icon' src='".$row['icon']."'/>";   
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "<img class='achiev_icon' style='opacity:0.4' src='".$row['icon']."'/>";   
        }

        echo "</div>";  
        echo "</div>";  
    }
```

Comment: Still, all of the icons are displayed with opacity: 0.4. echo $progres:100 

100 

100 

100 

100 

30 

20 

10 

40 

30 

20 

10 

10 

10 

10

Comment: Can you provide html output or css thats apply to achiev_icon class, maybe achiev_icon style overwrite element's style.

Comment: there was another style statement which was causing the problem. thank you miltos.